# Figure with vertices determined by adjacent trisectors of the angles of a rectangle

Tags: geometry

> Each angle of a rectangle is trisected. The intersections of the pairs of trisectors adjacent to the same side always form:
>
> $\textbf{(A)}\ \text{a square} \qquad \textbf{(B)}\ \text{a rectangle} \qquad \textbf{(C)}\ \text{a parallelogram with unequal sides}\\ \textbf{(D)}\ \text{a rhombus}\qquad \textbf{(E)}\ \text{a quadrilateral with no special properties}$

Solution

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Show that the diagonals of such quadrilateral are perpendicular (they are parallel to the sides of the rectangle) and they bisect each other.